# How does (or should) AlphaGoZero (which does chess) fare against Deep Blue?

Tags: chess, alphago-zero, deep-blue

Deep blue is good at chess, but is more "hand-coded" or "top-down".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)

AlphaGoZero is "self-taught", and at Go is very much super-human.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AlphaGo_Zero

How does AlphaGoZero fare when it goes head-to-head with DeepBlue?  Are there indicators like chess ratings?

Comment: Deep Blue is pretty primitive for todays best chess engines (e.g. Stockfish). Alpha Zero played Stockfish and beat it more times than it lost if I'm not mistaken. There are plenty of information online so you can reasearch about their games.

Comment: Thanks for "stockfish" reference.  I found this article on the subject. https://www.theringer.com/tech/2018/11/8/18069092/chess-alphazero-alphago-go-stockfish-artificial-intelligence-future

Comment: @EngrStudent Hi and welcome to AI SE! I just want to let you know that, in case you find an answer to your own question, you can write it below ;)